# Conditions for $x \mapsto x^k$ to be an automorphism

Tags: group-theory

I asked myself this question after I proved the following two exercises:

(1) Prove that a mapping from $U(16)$ (the group of units) to itself given by $x\mapsto x^3$ is an automorphism. What about $x^5$ and $x^7$. Generalize.

(2) Let $r\in U(n)$ (the group of units). Prove that the mapping $\alpha : Z_n \to Z_n$ defined by $s \mapsto rs$ is an automorphism.

I generalised (1) as follows:

(1G) The map $x \mapsto x^k$ is an automorphism of $U(n)$ if $\gcd(k,n)=1$.

Then I thought that (1) and (2) are almost the same exercise except one is in additive notation while the other is in multiplicative. Except that not quite: Number (2) is about finite cyclic groups -- the easiest of all examples while (1) may not be cyclic, but definitely Abelian.

So I started to wonder if one could generalise from these two and I came up with the following conjecture:

> Let $G$ be a finite Abelian group. Then the map $x \mapsto x^k$ is an
>   automorphism of $G$ if and only if $k$ and $|G|$ are coprime.

I had no trouble showing that if the order of $G$ and $k$ are coprime then this map is an automorphism: operation preserving is clear and if it's not injective then derive a contradiction. Done.

But the other direction seems not so obvious. So now I'm trying to show that if $x\mapsto x^k$ is an automorphism then $k$ and $|G|$ are coprime (while wondering whether it's actually true).

> Is it true or am I trying to prove something false?

Comment: What is $U(n)$?

Comment: @David I edited the question.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. The group of units in the ring $Z/nZ$?

Comment: @David I don't know, I haven't read the chapters on rings yet. $U(n)$ are all numbers between $1$ and $n$ that are coprime to $n$ under multiplication modulo $n$.

Comment: Okay, that's clear.

Comment: Unfortunately, (1G) is false. Take $k = 2$, $n = 3$.

Comment: Note that your first conjecture is not consistent with your (1G), because the order of $U(n)$ is not equal to $n$.

Comment: Okay, there are apparently two Davids answering here. The only way I see to use (2) to generalize (1) is if you know the results listed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n#Structure

Comment: Actually, another way is to prove your conjecture, which is true, using the structure theorem for finite Abelian groups. Then the appropriate generalization of (1) is that $x \mapsto x^k$ is an automorphism of $U(n)$ if and only if $\gcd(k,\phi(n)) = 1$.

Comment: If $\langle z \rangle = Z_n$ a map $z \to z^k$ is an automorphism only if $z^k$ is also a generator of $Z_n$. Your intuition is correct; this can indeed hold only if $k$ is prime to $n$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that there are two Davids. If only the avatars would show up next to the names!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if $x \mapsto x^k$ is an automorphism of the finite abelian group $G$, then in particular the order of $x$ and $x^k$ are equal. But $o(x^k)=\frac{o(x)}{gcd(k,o(x))}$. Hence $k$ is relatively prime to every order of any element of $G$. In particular (using Cauchy) $k$ is relatively prime to every prime divsior of $|G|$, that is $gcd(k,|G|)=1$. So yes your conjecture is true!

Answer (score 0):

If $k$ and $|G|$ are not coprime, take $p$ a prime divisor of both.

By Cauchy's theorem, there is an element of order $p$ in $G$.

This element is in the kernel of $x \mapsto x^k$, and so this map cannot be injective.