# Prove $k$ and $|G|$ is coprime when $\varphi_k(g)=g^k$ is a automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

The proposition is as follows:" Let $G$ be a finite Abelian group. Prove that $\varphi_k(g) = g^k$ is an endomorphism of $G$. If $\varphi_k$ is an automorphism of $G$, then $k$ and $|G|$ are coprime. "

I have already proven the endomorphism part, but I'm facing difficulties with the latter part of the proposition. I've attempted to use a proof by contradiction, trying to construct an element $g^{\frac{m}{(m,k)}}$, where $m$ is the order of the element $g$, in order to show that this mapping is not injective and leads to a contradiction. However, at the moment, $(m, k)$ could be $1$, and I'm unsure how to proceed.

I have seen the answer in
[Conditions for $x \mapsto x^k$ to be an automorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1617806/conditions-for-x-mapsto-xk-to-be-an-automorphism) but at this time I haven't studied neither Cauchy's theorem nor cyclic groups.

Comment: You really do need some kind of result in the vein of Cauchy's theorem, and I think any proof of this statement will essentially be reproving a part of Cauchy. Alternatively, you could probably find an explicit element by the structure theorem of finite abelian groups, but I suspect you haven't studied this if you haven't seen Cauchy.

Comment: The proposition is relatively early in our course materials. When encountering this question, we had just covered the basic concepts of group homomorphisms, isomorphisms, and the fundamental theorems of group homomorphisms. We hadn't even reached the point of studying cyclic groups yet.

Answer (score 2):

I did a proof **without** using Cauchy's theorem or theory of cyclic subgroups, as the OP wanted.
If $|G|=1$ then the result is trivial. We assume then that $|G|\not=1$. Suppose that there exists a prime divisor $p$ of $k$ which also divides $|G|$. Now, since $\varphi_k$ is an automorphism it follows that $\varphi_p$ is injective. To prove it let $g,h\in G$ such that $g^p=h^p$. Then $g^k=(g^p)^{k/p}=(h^p)^{k/p}=h^k$ and hence $g=h$. Thus, each $\varphi_p$ is injective. Since the composition of injections is an injection we have that $\varphi_{p^m}$ is also injective for each natural $m$. 
We consider $p^m$ to be the maximum power of $p$ dividing $|G|$. If we take $g\in G$ then
$$1^{p^m}=1=g^{|G|}=g^{\frac{|G|}{p^m}p^m}=(g^{\frac{|G|}{p^m}})^{p^m}.$$
Since $\varphi_{p^m}$ is injective we deduce that $g^{\frac{|G|}{p^m}}=1$. Denoting the order of an element $h\in G$ by $o(h)$, then it follows that $o(g)\mid\frac{|G|}{p^m}$ and hence $p\not\mid o(g)$ by the choice of $m$. Then, we shall prove that
$$p\not\mid o(g)\text{ for each }g\in G\implies p\not\mid|G|,$$
or equivalently,
$$p\mid|G|\implies\exists g\in G:p\mid o(g).$$
This will contradict the assumption that $k$ and $|G|$ have a common prime divisor $p$.
We consider the set $T=\{g\in G: p\not\mid o(g)\}$. If $T=\{1_G\}$ we are done. In other case, we take $1_G\not=g\in T$ of minimal order. If $n\in\mathbb Z$, then $(g^n)^{o(g)}=(g^{o(g)})^n=1$ and therefore $o(g^n)\mid o(g)$. We affirm that there exists $n\in\mathbb Z$ such that $p\mid o(g^n)$. If this does not occur then for each $n\in\mathbb Z$ it would hold $p\not\mid o(g^n)\leq o(g)$. The minimality of the order of $g$ implies in this case that $o(g^n)=o(g)$ for every $n\in\mathbb Z$. Taking $n=o(g)$ we obtain a contradiction, which concludes the proof.

Comment: You proved $\varphi_p$ is a bijection from $G$ to itself (since $G$ is finite, surjectivity is sufficient to prove this). You did not prove that it is an automorphism, because you did not prove that $(xy)^p = x^py^p$ for all $x,y\in G$. (And because you have not prove that $\varphi_p$ is a homomorphism, your argument for injectivity is incomplete; luckily you don't need it, as noted). I don't *think* you need to prove it is a homomorphism, though; it being a permutation of $G$ is already enough to conclude that $g^{p^m}=1$ implies $g=1$, since $\varphi_p$ sends $1$ to $1$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I didn't prove it because the OP proved that $\varphi_k$ is an endomorphism for a general $k$. But you're right, the homomorphism part is not necessary, the injectivity is enough.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the sketch of a proof.

If we assume by induction that all proper subgroups have order coprime to $k$, then either $|G|$ is coprime to $k$, or G is cyclic.  In the latter case, if $d$ divides $|G|$, it has an element of order $d$, and hence if also $d$ divides $k$ then $\phi_k$ has nontrivial kernel.